# Acessando configurações Wifi do android (IPV4)

Tags: java, android

Estou acessando as configurações de Wifi do Android, e está acusando como se eu estivesse buscando um IP padrão IPV6. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma propriedade do WifiConfiguration para definir como IPV4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para receber um **IP** com padrão **IPV4**, utilize o seguinte código:

```
public static String getIPV4 (){ 
    try {
        for (Enumeration enumeration = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); enumeration.hasMoreElements();){
            NetworkInterface nInterface = enumeration.nextElement();

            for (Enumeration IPenumeration = nInterface.getInetAddresses(); IPenumeration.hasMoreElements();){
            InetAddress netAdress = IPenumeration.nextElement();

            if (!netAdress.isLoopbackAddress()  &&  netAdress instanceof Inet4Address){ 
                    String IP4 = netAdress.getHostAddress().toString();
                    Toast.MakeText(getApplicationContext(), "IP: " + IP4, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return IP4;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException socketException) {
        Log.e("IP4 Erro", socketException.toString());
    }
    return null; 
}
```

Para resumir tudo isto, veja:

- `if(..., netAdress instanceof Inet4Address)`

A condição acima, verifica se o elemento recebido no `netAdress` é do tipo `Inet4Adress`. Isso era o que você precisa. Se você já usava um código semelhante a este, basta adicionar o operador `instanceof` em sua condição para comparar os elementos recebidos com o padrão **IPV4**.